# Angular v6, rxjs v6 error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I have updated code that worked fine with Angular 5.5/rxJS5.5 using the new **pipe** method to Angular 6/rxJS6 using the rxjs-lint package and the following commands

```
npm i -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p tsconfig.json
```

Imports etc have been amended as expected but now the code that worked fine with v5 of Angular/5.5 of RxJS is erroring with the error:

```
 error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, {} | RouterEvent | RouteConfigLoadStart | RouteConfigLoadEnd | ChildActivati...'.
```

I have removed the rxjs6-compat package but it makes no difference. It's almost as if the build thinks it's got an earlier version of rxJS than v5.5.  **package.json** used with npm install looks like this...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^3.0.3",
    "nsp": "^3.2.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-azure-ad": "^3.0.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

The import for rxjs operators are in rxjs6 format:

```
import { filter, map, merge, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The statement that worked but now gives this error is:

```
// Change page title on navigation or language change, based on route data
merge(this.translateService.onLangChange, onNavigationEnd)
  .pipe(
    map(() => {
      let route = this.activatedRoute;
      while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
      }
      return route;
    }),
    filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
    mergeMap(route => route.data)
  )
  .subscribe(event => {
    const title = event['title'];
    if (title) {
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.translateService.instant(title));
    }
  });
```

What have I missed?  Why is the pipe causing this error now where it was fine with rxJS 5.5?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
merge(this.translateService.onLangChange, onNavigationEnd).pipe(
```

with this

```
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd), 
  map(() => {
    let route = this.activatedRoute;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Been struggling with this for a few hours.

Comment: the patch is shown, but the cause of the error is unclear

Answer (score 32):

You should import merge like this:

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Could you provide additional detail on your answer, like what it's doing, why it works, etc.?

Comment: Presumably because they moved the operator from rxjs/operators to rxjs?

Comment: I was importing merge from 'rxjs/operators', switching to 'rxjs worked'

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. I got the same error with `combineLatest` and it turned out I had made the exact same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The merge operator should be imported from *"rxjs/observable"*.

Like this

```
import { merge } from "rxjs/observable/merge";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 kind of operators

**Observables**:

- imported from `'rxjs'` (formerly from `'rxjs/observable'`)
- they return an observable *you can pipe*
- they will be used at the beginning of the chain (never within a pipe)

**Operators**:

- imported from `'rxjs/operators'`
- they return an operator you will use within a pipe
- being an operator, there is no way to call `.pipe` on it, or you get the `TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction` error

The trap: some operators have the same name as an observable operator

For example:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
// This is the observable, you can `.pipe` it
combineLatest([a$,b$]).pipe(map(([a,b])=>{...}))
```

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
// This is the operator, it must be within a pipe.
// To prevent this ambiguity, this `combineLatest` is deprecated in rxjs7
// It has been renamed `combineLatestWith`.
a$.pipe(combineLatest(b$)).pipe(map(([a,b])=>{...}))
```